# Caching fully formed pages or individual elements of constantly changing data

Tags: python, mysql, memcached

It is viable to cache full user feeds similar to website like Twitter or Facebook, since they are usually constantly changing? Would the constant rewriting or expiring of the cache be worth the small window of time where the cache is actually effective?

Comment: I think you'll find out that the answer is 'no'.  You certainly don't want to be caching data for users who aren't online, etc.  EDIT: I just saw that you also mentioned pages - you can cache the template and fill in the custom part with dynamic (ajax, etc) calls when needed.